# graphics in pstricks, etc., not working

Tags: graphics

I'm using TeXworks and MiKTeX on Windows 7 Professional, and also LaTeX on a Linux machine, and including some graphics commands seen below.  On windows, the diagonal lines are not visible, and that might not be much of a problem although it's irritating.  But on Windows, I also get error messages about psarc and psline not being recognized, despite the inclusion of this:

```
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\psset{plotpoints=9,unit=3}
```

And on Linux I haven't been able to get the arrows to work right.  I had something like this:

```
\put(125,2){\psline(1,0){45}}
```

(Some numbers specifying locations of things have changed since I ran this; I don't think 125 and 2 would be right for what I have here.)  I had thought {45} would be the length of the arrow

It put an arrow where I wanted it but also showed the number 45.  So then I wrote

```
\put(125,2){\psline(1,0)}
```

without that number and it still put the arrow just where I wanted it, without the number 45.  How the end of the arrow ended up in the right place I don't know, but then I tried another arrow, and it ended up longer than what I wanted, and I have no idea what determines the length of the arrow or how to get it to be what I want.

I also haven't gotten \psarc to work.  I tried to follow an online manual that was a long pdf document; I don't have the URL just now.

I only need simple stuff: line segments, arrows, arcs of circles, and mathematical notation.  The line segments and the mathematical notation haven't been any problem at all; the rest isn't working.  What should I do?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\psset{plotpoints=9,unit=3}

\usepackage{eepic}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum.
%
\begin{figure}[h]
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.66mm}
\begin{picture}(100,130)(0,0)
% \thicklines
\put(80,8){\line(1,0){90}}
\put(170,8){\line(0,1){120}}
\put(80,8){\line(3,4){90}}
\put(90,13){$\theta$}
%  \psarc*[linewidth=1pt](10,8){20}{0}{53}
\put(175,68){$\tan\theta$}
\put(110,68){$\sec\theta$}
\put(120,0){$1$}
%  {\psset{arrows=->}
%  \put(125,2){\psline(1,0)}
%  \put(117,2){\psline(-1,0)} }
\put(74,0){$V$}
\end{picture}
\caption{}\label{big triangle}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a **complete** small document demonstrating the issue. Have you compared the versions of packages you are using and the version of TeX in the two cases?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to mix commands from `pict2e` and from `\pstricks`.

Comment: @Bernard : OK, you now see a complete file.

Comment: Are you trying to draw commutative diagrams?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina : Certainly not.  Why would you think that?

Comment: @MichaelHardy You mentioned arcs and arrows and some maths variables, so I thought you were trying to draw commutative diagrams. Could you please upload an image (it could be even a hand drawn image) of the kind of onject you are trying to draw?

Comment: There is a problem with the `units`: for the picture environment, it is `0.66 mm`, for `pstricks` it is 3, whih means 3cm. So the centre of your arc is set at (30cm, 24cm), which is outside of a normal page! Also I don't see why you load  `eepic`. I have an idea of what you want to draw, but (if I'm right) everything can be done very simply from within pstricks.

Comment: @Bernard : Actually the reason eepic is there is that I copied another file and deleted everything between \begin{document} and \end{document} and added some packages as appeared to be needed.

Comment: Could you describe what arc your `psarc*` command is supposed to draw? This is not clear to me.

Comment: @Bernard : The psarc* does not put the arc in the right place since I moved things around after I commented it out.  You should see a large right triangle with an angle of about 53 degrees in the lower left or the triangle.  This arc was to be centered at the vertex of that angle (I think that part is probably wrong in the code I posted here) and go from 0 to 53 degrees.  I wasn't bothering to be careful about getting the radius of the arc where I wanted it because I thought I'd attend to that after I saw the picture.

Comment: Yes I thought so, it looked like an illustations for trigonometric function, except the parameters for `psarc`  were quite strange…

Comment: I've now run it using the pict2e package and without eepic, and I find I can now see the diagonal line.  I haven't yet tried seeing if other stuff works better that way......

Comment: . . . and now I've run it without pict2e _and_ without eepic.  The diagonal line is visible, but psarc* still doesn't work.

Comment: @Bernard : Are you still here?

Answer (score 1):

Is that more or less what you want?

```
\documentclass[11pt, x11names, pdf]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{heuristica}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum.
%
\begin{figure}[!ht ]
\centering
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1,)(7,9)
\psset{unit=6,shortput = nab, linecolor = IndianRed3,arrows = c-c}
\pnodes(0,0){V}(1,0){A}(1,1.333){T}(1;53){M}
\uput[dl](V){$ V $}
\ncline[arrows = c-]{V}{A}\ncline[offset = -0.05, linewidth = 0.5pt, arrows = |<->|]{V}{A}\ncput*{1}
\ncline{T}{A}\ncline[offset = 0.05, linewidth = 0.5pt, arrows = |<->|]{T}{A}\ncput*[nrot=:U]{$ \tan θ $}
\ncline{V}{T}\ncline[offset = 0.05, linewidth = 0.5pt, arrows = |<->|]{V}{T}\ncput*[nrot=:U]{$ \sec θ $}
\psarc[linecolor =LightSteelBlue3,linewidth = 1.5pt](V){1}{0}{53}\uput[dl](1;27){$ θ $}
 \end{pspicture}
\caption{}\label{big triangle}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  That's definitely well on the way toward what I need.  I will need some arcs of circles without arrows, and some arrows like the ones surrounding the "1" also surrounding the \sec\theta and \tan\theta, and some other similar ones on at least one additional triangle yet to be drawn.  But the first snag I hit is that \ncline is an "undefined control sequence".  Is there some package that needs to be used for that?

Comment: ??? I don't understand.  It is a very common command, defined in `pst-node`, which is loaded by `pstricks-add`. Maybe you added unvoluntarily a spurious space, such as `\ ncline`. Did you try to compile the code "as is"?

Comment: @Michael Hardy: I've just modified my answer to adapt to some of your requirements.

Comment: I haven't yet tried running a file that is _verbatim_ the same as what you've got here; I just pasted some of your code into my file.  I will try that, and I also have a suspicion about something else.

Comment: OK, now I've tried running the file you've got above, verbatim.  I was told that fourier.sty was missing.  Before bothering with that, I removed the things about colors to see if that would make a difference.  Then I had to install about a half-dozen other files, including heuristica.sty, which was not in any of the "repositories" but could be found on the web.  Then I was told I needed mweights.sty, and similarly I had to go looking for that.  OK, next is etoolbox.sty.  Then fontaxes.sty.  Then caption.sty.  Then "'shell escape' (or 'write18') is not enabled: auto-pst-pdf will not work!"

Comment: I may have downloaded 20 style files so far in an attempt to get this code to run, and it doesn't run.

Comment: But does the code alone run? Of course you can delete the font style files (fourier and heuristica) which are there only because  only because I don't like Computer Modern. My package loading is minimalistic. and it should run by itself since it does for me.

Comment: Now I've deleted those and I've still got the error message about "shell escape" and auto-pst-pdf.

Comment: OK. I understand now. Let's continue in chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14788/discussion-between-bernard-and-michael-hardy).

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun!

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[PointSymbol=none](4,6)
    \pstGeonode[PointName={V,none},PosAngle=-135,CurveType=polygon,linecolor=red]{A}(4,0){B}(4,6){C}
    \pstMarkAngle[arrows=->,MarkAngleRadius=4]{B}{A}{C}{$\theta$}
    \pcline[offset=-8pt,linecolor=red]{|*-|*}(A)(B)\ncput*{1}
    \ncline[linestyle=none]{A}{C}\naput[nrot=:U]{$\sec \theta$}
    \ncline[linestyle=none]{C}{B}\naput[nrot=:U]{$\tan \theta$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In the course of running this I needed to download three style files and then I was told that \pstMarkAngle is an undefined control sequence.