# Still trying to draw a simple arc

Tags: graphics

Not having overcome the problems I asked about in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180733/graphics-in-pstricks-etc-not-working) question, I tried deleting from the LaTeX file I was working with all `\usepackage` commands except `\usepackage{curves}`.  I included this line in my file:

```
\put(80,8){\arc(10,0){53}}
```

I got an error message saying "bezier" is already defined, and it said this was on line 246, and my file doesn't have that many lines, so I went to line 246 of curves.sty and it was the end of a sequence of lines that started with \newcommand\@bezier.  So I commented those out and tried to compile again.  Then it said this:

```
\! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \fourteenrm 
                   \hss .
l.23 \put(80,8){\arc(10,0){53}}
```

The sequence "fourteenrm" appears nowhere either in my file nor in curves.sty.

So now I feel as if I've spent a week on something that should take a minute and I'm wondering if I should use xfig instead.

Does drawing an arc of a circle exceed the ability of all technology?

Comment: If you are willing to use TikZ, `\tikz\draw (10,0) arc(0:53:70.45)` will draw an arc from angle 0 to 73, and radius 70.45 (which is the distance between your center and starting point), starting at (10,0). Note however that by default Tikz uses centimeters as units, so this arc will be huge. You can appropiately scale the coordinates.

Comment: Can you post a complete-but-minimal document that shows what you are trying to do?  In general deleting or commenting out parts of style files will lead to problems.

Comment: And also, looking at your linked question, it might be worth adding some details on your set up?  Windows? MikTeX? If you have installed basic miktex it's normal for it to download packages on the fly.  If that bothers you, then install a complete system using the [net installer](http://miktex.org/download)

Comment: I'm using Windows and MikTeX on Windows.  I can use Linux machine, but not at home without some inconvenience.

Comment: So MiKTeX should be downloading the packages you are missing when they are needed. Have you changed anything which would prevent that from happening? It doesn't matter Windows or Linux. It is just that you seem to be missing a *lot* of fairly common packages. If you use MiKTeX, that is normal but it is also normal for them to be downloaded and installed automatically as needed. Otherwise, do a complete install as Thruston suggested or do an install of TeX Live.

Comment: OK, now I'm trying Tikz and it seems to be doing some good stuff.......

Comment: @MichaelHardy what is the status of this question? Are you still looking for solutions here?

Comment: @PaulGessler : I managed to do what I wanted with TikZ.

Comment: Excellent! :-) Please write up a self-answer so this question can be marked as solved. Alternatively, if you don't think the answer would be of use to others, you could delete the question. But I think it'd be good if you shared the knowledge with others here.

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded in getting what I wanted by using TikZ.  Thus

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick] (10,3) -- (18,3) -- (18,9) -- (10,3);
```

etc., drawing various lines, circles, arcs, and arrows and inserting mathematical notation in suitable places with lines like this:

```
\node at (9.15,7.8) {$\sec\theta\,d\theta$};
```